# Complex excel formula help needed?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I have a complex formula i need to create to look up various fields, with percentages of totals to be given if certain criteria are met, and need some guidance.

In column P i have a monetary figure.
In column D i have a business deal type, New Business, Renewal or Upsell.
In column T i have some Inside Sales users (some are blank depending if they assisted)

If a deal is New Business or Upsell I need to work out the % of the monetary figure. (renewals excluded).

If the deal has an Inside Sale usernames i need to calculate 3% of the monetary figure), however if the deal doesn't have an inside Sales user assigned i need to calculate 2% of the monetary figure.

If anyone can assist i would be very grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You should be able to use ISBLANK here too.] Hopefully this is what you want:

[image: SU565092 example]

The logic is "Where Renewal, show 0, otherwise if T is blank apply 2%, else apply 3%".

Comment: pnuts, I think you need to put in a condition to exclude Renewals from the % of monetary amount calculation.

Comment: thanks guys much appreciated as always. You mentioned a condition to exclude renewals from the monetary amount, however i think the D2=Renewal,0 formula has catered for this. I have gone through the sheet and can see all renewals have returned a $0

Comment: I have used the below formula to calculate to commission percentage of a certain deal =IF($D97="Renewal",0,IF(ISBLANK($T97),$P97*0.026,$P97*0.031) what i now need to is look up a certain entry in Column C, such as NZ, and if so need to add an exchange rate of 0.8, any ideas how to automate this as opposed to just adding *0.8 at the end of the formual manually?

Comment: the same percentages will apply, however there are deals from both ANZ & NZ, and for the NZ ones i need to represent the dollar figure as if it was in AUD, hence the 0.8